# Sync Google spreadsheet to Google Calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api, synchronization

In Google apps, I have created a Form that users will fill out to request to borrow a laptop. From this I have the responses spreadsheet. Now with the responses spreadsheet I want to be able to automatically push that to a shared calendar. It doesnt necessarily have to be automatic, there can be a button that says 'Update calendar' for example.

Headers are 'Timestamp' in A1 (which i dont need in the calendar), 'Name' in B1 which i will require, 'Start Date' in C1 (which will be needed), 'Time if Collection' in D1 (which is not necessary), and 'Return Date' in E1 which is necessary.

I have also tried coding myself by grabbing examples but am really not experienced in this so having trouble.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this isn't really an answer but its to big for a comment.

I think you are going to have some problems with this.   You need permissions to be able to save to said calendar.    Normally I would tell you to use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) this *would* enable you to buy pass the hole [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) request authentication thing.

But ... Google App scripts (I am assuming this is what you mean) is JavaScript you can't use a service account with JavaScript.  I also don't think you can hack a refresh token type thing with JavaScript.   I haven't tried and I'm not sure if I would due to security issues.

IMO you will need to look into some kind of server sided scripting language, or start giving everyone access to the calendar so that you can use normal oauth2.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response. Really appreciated. I dont think permissions will be an issue when saving to the calendar. Firstly i'm a system admin and it's one i've created myself. Second, i've managed to write to it using the script as a guideline in the following link...  http://www.adammcfarland.com/2013/08/09/tutorial-using-google-spreadsheets-to-update-a-google-calendar-our-new-vacation-management-system/

JUst need to adjust that script to meet my headers in the spreadsheet if possible.

Thanks again :-)

Comment: if you can write to it that's fine. but have someone else test it make sure it still works when they are logged in.

Comment: Will do. Thanks matey